# How do I use check_log (Nagios plugin) to query only lines that are different from pattern?

Tags: regex, nagios, logfiles

Example:

```
[Fri Oct 18 17:39:11 2013] [error] [client x.x.x.x] client denied by server configuration: /home/client/client.com.br/app/etc/local.xml
[Fri Oct 18 17:39:38 2013] [error] [client x.x.x.x] client denied by server configuration: /home/client/client.com.br/app/etc/local.xml
[Fri Oct 18 17:39:44 2013] [error] [client x.x.x.x] client denied by server configuration: /home/client/mariapiacasa.com.br/app/etc/local.xml
[Fri Oct 18 17:42:41 2013] [error] [client x.x.x.x] client denied by server configuration: /home/client/client.com.br/app/etc/local.xml
[Fri Oct 18 17:47:33 2013] [error] [client x.x.x.x] client denied by server configuration: /home/client/client.com.br/app/etc/local.xml
[Fri Oct 18 17:47:49 2013] [error] [client x.x.x.x] client denied by server configuration: /home/client/client.com.br/app/etc/local.xml
[Fri Oct 18 17:47:58 2013] [error] [client x.x.x.x] client denied by server configuration: /home/client/client.com.br/app/etc/local.xml
[Fri Oct 18 17:50:02 2013] [error] [client x.x.x.x] client denied by server configuration: /home/client/client.com.br/app/etc/local.xml
[Fri Oct 18 17:59:37 2013] [error] [client x.x.x.x] client denied by server configuration: /home/client/client.com.br/app/etc/local.xml
[Fri Oct 18 19:05:34 2013] [error] [client x.x.x.x] File does not exist: /home/client/client.com.br/skin/frontend/default/MAG080138
```

In this example I do not want to be monitored lines with the message **client denied by server configuration: /home/client/client.com.br/app/etc/local.xml**.
Everything else should be monitored.
I know how to find what I do not want to appear with the following regex:

```
.*client denied by server configuration:.*\/app\/etc\/local\.xml$
```

In the above example should be monitored only the line:

```
[Fri Oct 18 19:05:34 2013] [error] [client x.x.x.x] File does not exist: /home/client/client.com.br/skin/frontend/default/MAG080138
```

Answer (score 0):

In regex you can use a [negative lookahead](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html), using the `(?!<regexpression>)`, to match something if and only if it is not followed by something else.

So in order to match any line that does not contain the expression:

```
client denied by server configuration:.*\/app\/etc\/local\.xml
```

You can use the negative lookahead in this way:

```
 ^(?:.(?!client denied by server configuration:.*\/app\/etc\/local\.xml))*$
   ^ non capture group
     ^ any character
      ^not followed by 
         ^ your regex
```

(see it in [action](http://regex101.com/r/aG0sB2))

However, this regex will perform a lot better:

```
^.* \[client x.x.x.x\] (?!client denied by server configuration:.*\/app\/etc\/local\.xml).*$
```

(see it in [action](http://regex101.com/r/sG6xM2))

since the negative lookahead is performed only once instead of after every character match.

Hope this helps.

Good luck!